# Cannot call local REST Api from android device

Tags: java, android, rest

I am trying to call a local REST API from my android device. The call works fine from the emulator but I get an error with connection failed when I try from my device.

The server from which I try making the call is a Java SpringBoot application. I have tried to access the URL with the computer IP (from ipconfig) and with the public IP as well. Only he computer IP works for the emulator. Both the pc and the android device are on the same network so that shouldn't be a problem.

The code from android client side:

```
public interface UserService{

    String BASE_URL = "http://ip:8080/";

    @GET("users/{id}")
    Call<User> getUser(@Path("id") int userId);

    @POST("login")
    Call<LoginResponseDto> login(@Body LoginDto loginDto);

    @POST("users")
    Call<User> register(@Body RegisterDto registerDto);
}
```

Where ip is my PC's ip.

```
public LoginResponseDto login(LoginDto loginDto) throws IOException {
        final LoginResponseDto[] user = {new LoginResponseDto()};
        Call<LoginResponseDto> loginCall = userService.login(loginDto);
        Response<LoginResponseDto> response = loginCall.execute();
        if (response.code() == 401) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                System.out.println("MESSAGE = " + jObjError.getString("message"));
                throw new RuntimeException(jObjError.getString("message"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        user[0] = response.body();
        return user[0];
    }
```

I'm expecting a successful login call to the server with a LoginResponseDto returned and a homepage activity starting.Instead, when calling loginCall.execute() I get:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /my_pc_ip (port 8080) from /some_ip (port 45074) after 10000ms.
```

I don't what who's is some_ip.

Comment: you need to connect you phone with your computer hotspot or configure your computer or router to share these ports

Comment: Its almost certainly being blocked at the router

Comment: I have connected them through my mobile data, using the hotspot from my android device with my PC.

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have solved this by making the port to which tomcat deploys the app public. You can do that by entering windows firewall and adding a new inbound rule for that port(usually 8080 or 8081).